# Rails: overriding model name in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have the following model:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  # model code stuff
end
```

In the controller, I can do something like that:

```
class ActionsController < ApplicationController
  # super simple update
  def update
    @action = Action.find(params[:id])
    @action.update_attributes(params[:action])
  end
end
```

Is it possible to make my Action model to be represented by 'something_action' in params array without renaming the model itself?  I.e. so I can retrieve it like that:

```
@action.update_attributes(params[:something_action])
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

In your form_for use :as => :some_other_params_name

```
form_for(@action, :as => :different
```

Comment: That works!  For the record, I wonder if there is a way to do it decoratively on the model itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `form_for`, you can change it to

```
form_for :something_action, @action do |f|
```

so it uses `:something_action` as the name of the params